# Print original input order of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, printing

**How do I print out my dictionary in the original order I had set up?**

If I have a dictionary like this:

```
smallestCars = {'Civic96': 12.5, 'Camry98':13.2, 'Sentra98': 13.8}
```

and I do this:

```
for cars in smallestCars:
    print cars
```

it outputs:

```
Sentra98
Civic96
Camry98
```

but what I want is this:

```
Civic96
Camry98
Sentra98
```

Is there a way to print the original dictionary in order without converting it to a list?

Comment: Thats hashing :) not sorted in any order

Comment: But why the order changed when printing it, Why it is not printing as assigned

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A *regular* dictionary doesn't have order. You need to use the `OrderedDict` of the `collections` module, which can take a list of lists or a list of tuples, just like this:

```
import collections

key_value_pairs = [('Civic86', 12.5),
                   ('Camry98', 13.2),
                   ('Sentra98', 13.8)]
smallestCars = collections.OrderedDict(key_value_pairs)

for car in smallestCars:
    print(car)
```

And the output is:

```
Civic96
Camry98
Sentra98
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are not required to keep order. Use `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for car in sorted(smallestCars.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]):
...     print car[0]
... 
Civic96
Camry98
Sentra98
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the dictionary, python doesn't care about in what order you wrote the elements and it won't remember the order after the object is created. You cannot expect it(regular dictionary) to print in the same order. Changing the structure of your code is the best option you have here and the [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is a good option as others stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tuple (nested) array to do this:

```
smallestCars = [['Civic86', 12.5],
               ['Camry98', 13.2],
               ['Sentra98', 13.8]]

for car, size in smallestCars:
    print(car, size)

# ('Civic86', 12.5)
# ('Camry98', 13.2)
# ('Sentra98', 13.8)
```